# loop on a map same way as array

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I'm trying to loop on containers(map, set,vector,list) and array the same way.
Here is the code:

```
template<typename TYPE>
void AddXmlOfContAttribute(TYPE *it)
{
    m_ss<<"<SingleNode ";
    AddXmlAttribute("Value" , *it);
    m_ss<<"/>\n";
}



template<typename TYPE1,typename TYPE2>
void AddXmlOfContAttribute(std::pair<TYPE1,TYPE2> tpair)
{
    m_ss<<"<MapNode ";
    AddXmlAttribute("key"   , tpair->first);
    AddXmlAttribute("Value" , tpair->second);
    m_ss<<"/>\n";
}




template<typename TYPE>
    void AddContainerToXml(std::string str, TYPE it_begin ,  TYPE it_end)
    {
        if(it_begin != it_end)
        {
            m_ss<<"<"<<str<<">\n";

            //std::for_each(it_begin , it_end, AddXmlOfContAttribute);

            for( ; it_begin != it_end ; it_begin++)
                AddXmlOfContAttribute(it_begin);

            m_ss<<"</"<<str<<">\n";
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

> In member function ‘void AddElementToBackupFileFunctor::AddContainerToXml(CrString,
>        TYPE, TYPE) [with TYPE = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >]’
>       instantiated from here
>       error: no matching function for call to
>   AddElementToBackupFileFunctor::AddXmlOfContAttribute(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >&)’

How do i do it in normal loop?
Bonus question :How do i do it in for_each loop?

Answer (score 1):

So, in short, I have constructed an example that should explain all you need [here](http://ideone.com/D4Xba).

In order to do what you want, you have to first change your handlers to structs with static methods (this is required because you cannot partially specialize function templates, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318458/template-specialization-of-template-class)):

```
template<typename TYPE>
struct value_handler {
    static void AddXmlOfContAttribute(AddElementToBackupFileFunctor& context, 
                                      TYPE value) {
        // handle normal values here
        // context replaces this-pointer
    }
};

// partial specialization for pairs
template<typename TYPE1, typename TYPE2>
struct value_handler<std::pair<TYPE1, TYPE2> > {
    static void AddXmlOfContAttribute(AddElementToBackupFileFunctor& context, 
                                      std::pair<TYPE1, TYPE2> value) {
        // handle values that are pairs here
        // context replaces this-pointer
    }
};
```

The `value`-parameters cannot be references, because that would screw up `std::bind1st` (a workaround using Boost is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349973/why-did-it-compile-errorly-when-i-added-a-reference-argument-to-a-member-function/5350014#5350014)). To use this with `std::for_each`, do the following:

```
std::for_each(begin, end, std::bind1st(
    std::ptr_fun(&AddElementToBackupFileFunctor::value_handler<typename TYPE::value_type>::AddXmlOfContAttribute), 
    *this));
```

Comment: Ok , what about the call to the map function?
Can i also call it with TYPE & ?

Comment: AddXmlOfContAttribute(std::pair<TYPE1,TYPE2> tpair)

Comment: This is what the second part of my answer shows. I will explain further in a moment.

Comment: @David: I have posted a new answer that does the automatic specialization you want with `std::for_each`.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. 
I think i'll use the regular loop solution.
I don't see any advatage in using for_each.
Tell me if i'm wrong but, ususally for_each is only a matter of esthetic. And here it made it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error comes from this line:

```
AddXmlOfContAttribute(it_begin);
```

This should be:

```
AddXmlOfContAttribute(*it_begin);
```

I am a moron I didn't realize the first overload... that should be the reference as sc said.